# Matrix multiplication using 2d vector

Tags: c++, matrix, vector

Following is my code:

```
void matrix(int rowsInA, int columnsInA, int columnsInB){




    std::vector< vector<int> > a; 
    std::vector< vector<int> > b;


    for (int i = 0; i < rowsInA; i++) {
        vector<int> myRow(1);
        a.push_back(myRow);
        for (int j = 0; j < columnsInA-1; j++) {

            int x = rand() % 100;;
            myRow.push_back(x);

        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rowsInA; i++) {
        vector<int> myRow(1);
        b.push_back(myRow);
        for (int j = 0; j < columnsInB-1; j++) {
            int x = rand() % 100;;
            myRow.push_back(x);

        }
    }
    std::vector< vector<int> > c = multiply(a, b);

    for (int i = 0; i < rowsInA; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columnsInB; j++) {
            cout << c[i][j];
        }

    }
}

std::vector< vector<int> > multiply(std::vector< vector<int> > a , std::vector< vector<int> > b) {
    int rowsInA = 9;
    int columnsInA = 9; // same as rows in B
    int columnsInB = 9;
    std::vector< vector<int> > d;

    for (int i = 0; i < rowsInA; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columnsInB; j++) {
            vector<int> myRow;
            myRow.push_back(a[i][0]);
            d.push_back(myRow);

            for (int k = 0; k < columnsInA; k++) {

                myRow.push_back(myRow[i]+ a[i][k] * b[k][j]);//error here
            }
        }
    }
    return d;
}
```

first function matrix() creates two vector within a vector and assigns random values to it and then call multiply in which vectors are multiplied.
It is giving vector subscript out of range error

Comment: What say your debugger ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < rowsInA; i++) {
        vector<int> myRow(1);
        a.push_back(myRow);
        for (int j = 0; j < columnsInA-1; j++) {
            int x = rand() % 100;;
            myRow.push_back(x);
        }
    }
```

Constructs a single element vector, pushes it on to `a`, appends some
values to your temporary, and then throws it away.  C++ is not Java or C#.  The vector at the back of `a` is not changed by changes to `myRow`.

You also seem to be putting a fixed value as the first element of `myRow`, and
then appending randomness to it.  Is that what you meant?

What you need is:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < rowsInA; i++) {
        vector<int> myRow;
        myRow.reserve(columnsInA);
        myRow.push_back(0);  // First element fixed.
        for (int j = 1; j < columnsInA; j++) {
            const int x = rand() % 100;;
            myRow.push_back(x);
        }
        a.push_back(myRow);
    }
```

Alternatively, making all the values random, and working directly with the vector:

```
    a.reserve(rowsInA);
    for (int i = 0; i < rowsInA; i++) {
        a.push_back( {} );
        a.back().reserve(columnsInA);
        for (int j = 0; j < columnsInA; j++) {
            const int x = rand() % 100;;
            a.back().push_back(x);
        }
    }
```

You have a similar problem with initializing B, and your multiply loop needs to accumulate `a[i][k] * b[k][j]` into a temporary sum, then push that onto `myRow`, and finally push `myRow` onto `d`.

Finally, when you have got this working, look up how to write a Matrix class that stores all the data in a vector with rows*cols elements and then uses an indexing function to refer to it.  Your cache will thank you.